# upstart writing to syslog in a simple way

Tags: shell, ubuntu, pipe, syslog, upstart

I have an [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) script that uses

```
pre-start script
  exec >/dev/kmsg 2>&1
  echo starting program
  # run my program here
  npm install
  node app.js
end script
```

to redirect output of a program to `/etc/var/syslog`.

It seems to be broken since writing to `/dev/kmsg` is not possible anymore in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (I have another machine with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS that it is working fine)

Anyone can think of an alternate way ?

Answer (score 1):

I have used logger instead of `/dev/kmsg` which also writes to `/var/log/syslog`

Surround your upstart pre, post and start scripts like this :

```
pre-start script
{
  echo starting program
  # run my program here
  npm install
  node app.js
} 2>&1 | logger -t app
end script
```

You should start seeing your app's logs appear in syslog

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```